# is_front_page, is_page('slug'), is_page(id) not working

Tags: conditional-content

None of the following are working to display conditional format in the sidebar when the current page is the home page:

- is_front_page,
- is_page('home'),
- is_page(id)

I added an else clause which is implemented on the home page.

In Options > Reading, I have specified a page called Home to be the front page.  The slug 'home' and the page id of 13 (obtained from the URL when editing the Home page) all return false.

If I place `<?php the_ID(); ?>` in the sidebar, it displays the post ids of blog posts which are also displayed (title only) by home.php (which is the template assigned to the home page).

I don't know how else to explicitly display the page id on the front end so I know I'm using the correct id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting a [wp_reset_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) function call after your loop on the homepage template.

If you're using a custom query on the home page and not used `wp_reset_query`, then the conditional check will always point to the last post fetched by that custom query hence failing to check if homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing exactly what's going in your code, it sounds like the spot you are testing the page ID within the sidebar is already within a loop displaying posts on your sidebar.

Try running your conditional test before the sidebar loop begins, possibly storing it in a different variable in your home.php file and checking that variable in the sidebar instead of the current post ID